# Whats default protocol used by ibm mq broker for JMS interface

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, mqtt

We are using IBM MQ as MoM for Java based JMS application. I need to know the underlying communication protocol used by ibm mq. Specifically, if I need to communicate using MQTT protocol with IBM MQ, do I need to use MQ Telemetry product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MQ JMS client will use a proprietary protocol to communicate to the queue manager rather than the MQTT protocol. This proprietary protocol is not published externally like the MQTT protocol is.

If you need to use the MQTT protocol then you will need to use a MQTT client.

Comment: Thanks @whitfiea, can I use default mq jms client to use mqtt protocol ?

Comment: @everCurious you can't use the mq jms client to use the mqtt protocol.  You will need to use an MQTT client such as Eclipse Paho or look at this documentation: [link] (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/tt20025_.htm?lang=en)